# What is the permitted mapping type in elasticsearch-7.0?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am migrating my code from Elasticsearch-5.6 to Elasticsearch-7.0. What is the allowed mapping type that I should use?

As per the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types

For Elasticsearch 7.x
"... indexing a document no longer requires a document type. ... _doc is a permanent part of the path, and represents the endpoint name rather than the document type."

This seems pretty clear, but I was able to execute both of the following successfully:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/twitter/doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"x":"val"}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/twitter/_doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"x":"val"}'
```

As per the documentation, inserting at /index_name/doc should not function, as /_doc is part of the endpoint-path.

Am I missing something from the documentation?

(My migration strategy would depend on this, as Elasticsearch-5 does not allow type names with preceding '_' (e.g. '_doc') and I would want to change my code to write to 'doc' if that works with Elasticsearch-7)

Comment: Types are gone in version 7. one index one type

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But is the url supposed to contain '_doc' compulsorily? Documentation says so, but seems any other works as well.

Comment: It does work. Even if you use type name as `xyz`, that will work too but it has now become irrelevant and going ahead it will be removed and only endpoint will work. That is why it is recommended to keep type name as `_doc`.